# Group totals conditionally based on field values

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am trying to query different documents from MongoDB via pymongo and group them by specific fields. The grouping part works really well, but I have a field that has a boolean value (True, False), but currnently it is keeping documents with True and documents with False in a separate grouping.

For example:

```
doc1{boolean : True, ... ... ..., count = 20}
doc2{boolean : False, ... ... ..., count = 10}
```

But I need it to group it like that:

```
doc{boolTrue : 20, boolFalse, 10, ... ... ..., count = 30}
```

So that it would not separate the documents by the boolean field.

I tried to do something like that, but neither of the proposed (see below) solutions didn't work:

```
"$group": {
    "_id": {
       "succTrue": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$client.succeeded": "True"}, 1, 0]}},
       "succFalse": {"$cond": [{"$client.succeeded": "False"}, 1, 0]},
    }
}
```

PS: There are other fields as well, but they are not relevant for the question.

E: Actual documents look something like that:

```
{
    "sType" : "Client",
    "succeeded" : false,
    "sVer" : "v1"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    countSucceededTrue: 15,
    countSucceededFalse: 5,
    "sType" : "Client",
    "sVer" : "v1"
},
{
    countSucceededTrue: 5,
    countSucceededFalse: 13,
    "sType" : "Client",
    "sVer" : "v2"
}
{
    countSucceededTrue: 3,
    countSucceededFalse: 2,
    "sType" : "Client",
    "sVer" : "v3"
}
```

Comment: What do the actual documents look like? What is the output you are expecting? Your statement attempt is wrong in quite a few places so samples of input and output are far more useful.

Comment: Edited the question with expected output & actual docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your "grouping keys" in the `_id` field, and the other conditions under [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulators:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "sType": "$sType", "sVer": "$sVer" },
    "countSucceededTrue": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$succeeded", 1, 0 ] } },
    "countSucceededFalse": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$succeeded", 0, 1 ] } }
  }}
])
```

The "grouping key" is of course nested, but you should get used to the that concept. It is possible to do another pass to rename fields with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), but the cost is running through all results rather than just accepting that these are nested within `_id`:

```
collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "sType": "$sType", "sVer": "$sVer" },
    "countSucceededTrue": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$succeeded", 1, 0 ] } },
    "countSucceededFalse": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$succeeded", 0, 1 ] } }
  }},
  { "$project": {
     "sType": "$_id.sType",
     "sVer": "$_id.sVer",
     "countSucceededTrue": 1,
     "countSucceededFalse": 1
  }}
])
```

The [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is a ["ternary"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), so where the first condition "if" is logically true ( and it's already a boolean ) "then" use the second argument "else" use the value of the third. This supplies the "count" to the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator.